# For loop - Bash isn't reading my variables

Tags: bash, for

I am trying to make a little bash script, that calls a command on each of my files in have in a file, found with the `find` command.

I want to be able to keep track of where the script stopped (it tends to crash) so i can take back from there. I managed to read my file, get the lines,... But currently i'm stuck at the for loop. I want to do a C style for loop, starting at the the last line i stopped at, increment by one, and do it as long as i'm smaller than the number of lines. I got this :

```
#!/bin/bash

LINES=$(wc -l < file.txt)
LASTLINE=$(grep -P '### Stop marker ###' file.txt | wc -l)
STARTFROM=$(($LINES - $LASTLINE))

for ((i = STARTFROM; i < LINES; i++));
do
    echo "we are processing file number $i"
    file=sed -n $i'p' file.txt
    ocrmypdf [some stuff] -input $file
done
```

Here is an excerpt of what my `file.txt` looks like inside

```
./input_folder/hard_blurry.pdf
./input_folder/l_ordre_malte.pdf
### Stop marker ###
./input_folder/single_page.pdf
./input_folder/very_hard.pdf
```

When i run this i get... nothing. Bash doesn't enter the loop at all. I tried setting ints directly, and it worked, which tells me that the vars are bein read as string.

I tried all these ways to write my var :

```
for ((i = STARTFROM; i < LINES; i++));
for ((i = $((STARTFROM)); i < $((LINES)); i++));
for ((i = $(echo STARTFROM); i < $(echo LINES); i++));
```

and nothing works. I'm suprised that no erros are thrown as well. My Os is ubuntu 20.0.4

Its content is the path to the files i want to work with.

Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: Actually, this is not the way I would do it in a shell script. Are you aware that you are scanning the file several times for `grep`ping, for line counting and finally for the actual task? I'd suggest to do a `while` loop over `read`ing the file, set a flag on the `Stop marker` line and perform "some stuff" after the marker was set.

Comment: `LASTLINE` is always 1 or how many "Stop Makers" do you have?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do. Please provide some example input and expected output. What are you doing @ `//some stuff` ? Also make sure to read [What is the XY Problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and tell us about your "little bash script" which fails.

Comment: @pLumo last line is supposed to be the last occurrence of my flag. So an int, at most as big as the line number. "some stuff" can be anything; my problem is that i don't enter the loop. Currently it's `echo "i is $i"`

Comment: @Philippos How would you do it ? please suggest me something, if it's a problem you've already encountered. For the grep, is it really repeated ? I tried to only get the value returned by it, since i don't actually need to `grep`more than once each time i run the script. I'm also concerned about huge files

Comment: `LASTLINE=$(grep -P '### Stop marker ###' file.txt | wc -l)` is not the line number, but the number of *Stop markers* in your file. And `-P` is not needed, you have a fixed string.

Comment: You should `echo` your variables before the `for` loop... `$LASTLINE` might be 0 (e.g. because your Stop Marker is not found. Then you'd have `LINE == STARTFROM`, which would explain that the loop is not entered.

Comment: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/7696).    Use perl or awk or python (or anything **except** shell) for processing text files, shell is precisely the wrong tool for the job....shell is a great wrapper for running other programs to process text, but terrible at processing text itself.

Comment: BTW, to get the line number where a string occurs in a file, you can use `grep -n`.  e.g. `grep -n -F '### Stop marker ###' file.txt | head -n 1 | cut -d: -f1`.   But it's much easier to use awk.  e.g. `awk '/### Stop marker ###/  {print NR; exit}' file.txt`

Comment: @cas i think you're right. I was trying to refine a script to save some time, but i'll probably be better off using python directly

Comment: If you want to track errors in your bash scripts using: `set -o errexit` (abort on nonzero exitstatus), `set -o nounset` (abort on unbound variable) and `set -o pipefail` (don't hide errors within pipes) could be useful. I actually set those with vim as automatic header whenever I create a new *.sh file. Two of those commands are explained here if you want more info: https://ricma.co/posts/tech/tutorials/bash-tip-tricks/ .

Comment: While I agree with the comments about incorrect shell scripting or bad shell practice, you could use `set -x` to print all commands the shell executes, including the values of variables in those commands. Switch debug output off with `set +x`.

Comment: @Orsu, I meant some like that: `process=false; while read line; do if $process; then YOUR_PROGRAM_TO_DO_STUFF_WITH "$line"; fi; if [[ "$line" == "### Stop marker ###" ]]; then process=true; fi; done < file.txt`. That said, if that "some stuff" can be done with python, use python for the file processing as well.

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: You should be running `some stuff` directly from `find` using `-exec`.  It is unclear what you want to achieve with your script. The computations that you seem to want to carry out makes no sense from the point of view of wanting to continue processing from some stop point.

Comment: @Orsu, looking at the lack of answers you're getting, I wonder, could you [edit] the question to add a short sample of the input file your script reads, and what exactly it's supposed to do with it? With all the important parts included, like those stop markers. Just some dummy data in place of the parts you already know how to do, of course.

Comment: @ilkkachu sure, i'm doing it

Answer (score 2):

```
LASTLINE=$(grep -P '### Stop marker ###' file.txt | wc -l)
```

This will tell you *how many* lines match that pattern, but not where they are. If there's one marker in the file, this returns `1`.
You'd need to use something like `grep -n` (`--line-number`) to get the line numbers.

```
file=sed -n $i'p' file.txt
```

That should probably be `file=$(sed ...)`, i.e. with a command substitution to capture the output of `sed`. But, if you do that in a loop, you read the whole file for each iteration of the loop, a silly waste, and will take ages if the file is long.

That's the sort of thing the question
[Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) that was linked here earlier refers to. Note that the bad practice is *processing*, modifying text. Running commands based on some data in a file using the shell is just fine; the shell exists to run commands.

So, just loop over the file once and detect the stop marker in the shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
while IFS= read -r line; do 
    if [[ $line == '### Stop marker ###' ]]; then
        break;
    fi
    i=$((i + 1))
    echo "line $i, do some stuff with '$line'"
done < file.txt
```

(`[[ .. ]]` is a Ksh-ism. It could be replaced with `case` in a POSIX shell.)

Or, have some external text processing tool deal with the stop marker and have the shell just run the commands:

```
#!/bin/sh
i=0
< file.txt sed -n -e '/### Stop marker ###/q' -e p |
while IFS= read -r line; do
    i=$((i + 1))
    echo "line $i, do some stuff with '$line'"
done
```

**If** you really wanted to do a `for (i = 0; i < end; i++)` style loop, you could read the whole file into an array first, but unless you need
random access to the lines, that's completely unnecessary. Streaming through the file is far more natural.

Answer (score -2):

you can treid like this seq to get range of var:

```
#!/bin/bash
LINES=1
LASTLINE=10
for i in $(seq $LINES $LASTLINE )
do
 echo $i
done
```

output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: Doesn't work in bash, though it does in ksh93 and zsh (which are not allowed by the Q). There are at least dozens of existing Qs/As that cover this, so you evidently haven't read any of them _or_ tested.

Comment: yes,in bash {$var1..$var2} not work, you shoud be use seq to generate number

Comment: This answer describes a loop structure but doesn't really address OP question.